# How do you do test helpers with R's testthat?

Tags: r, testing, tdd

Does anyone know how to use helper methods for tests in the testthat package?

For example, my test that an array has a distribution that is not to far away from a Gaussian:

```
expect_not_too_ungaussian <- function(x){
    x <- (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)
    test <- ks.test(x, pnorm)
    expect_true(test$p.value > .2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a logical and test that.

```
expect_not_too_ungaussian <- function(x){
    x <- (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)
    test <- ks.test(x, pnorm)
    return(test$p.value > .2)
}

expect_true(expect_not_too_ungaussian(x))
```